# Drawing underscores upside down without unicode in Java

Tags: java, class, oop

I want to produce a drawing that looks like this (with an output of two lines) where the top of the drawing is an upside-down underscore: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFu0R.png)

Instead it is outputting everything on the same line. I also do not want to use UNICODE.

```
public class Landscape {

    String terrainString1;
    String terrainString2;

    Landscape(){
        terrainString1="";
        terrainString2="";
    }

    public void flat(int lengthOfFlatPortion){
        for (int count=0; count<lengthOfFlatPortion; count++){
            terrainString1+=" ";
            terrainString2+="_";
        }
    }
    public void hill(int lengthOfHillTop){
        terrainString1=" ";
        terrainString2="/";
        for (int count=0; count<lengthOfHillTop; count++){
            terrainString1+="_";
            terrainString2+=" ";
        }
        terrainString1+=" ";
        terrainString2+="\\";
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(terrainString1);
        System.out.println(terrainString2);
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Landscape landscape = new Landscape();

        landscape.flat(3);
        landscape.hill(5);
        landscape.flat(2);
        landscape.hill(3);
        landscape.flat(4);
        landscape.hill(0);
        landscape.flat(2);

        landscape.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first two lines in `hill` should use `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: @tkausl Omg what a silly mistake thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this violates your "no Unicode" requirement, but there is the 'Macron' character ( ¯ ) at ASCII 238 that could work, depending on the font chosen.

```
__/¯¯\__/¯\_     // This is a test of Macron character
```

Otherwise, if Unicode is a possibility, there's a specific 'overline' character ( ‾ ) (U+203E).

```
__/‾‾\__/‾\_     // This is a test of overline character
```